# Queue Skipping First Item in Queue (Python multiprocessing.Queue)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4B (1GB) & Macbook Pro

OS: Raspbian & OSX

Python Version: 3.7.3

I'm having an issue with multiprocessing.Queue() skipping the first item that is placed in the queue. After some testing I have figured out that I can keep this from happening if I add additional code (time.sleep(.0001), print(''), anything except for commented code) between the subsequent q.put() commands. q.get will always skip the first item in the queue and start on the second item without a delay between adding items to the queue, and when a delay is added, it will always get the first item in the queue. Maybe someone can explain to me what is happening and how to resolve this issue in a better way. Thanks in advance.

Here is a sample bit of code that shows the problem that I'm having*(see note).

```
import multiprocessing
import time

set_size = 3

def process_queueing():
    entry = 1
    data_list = []
    for i in range(1,100):
        data_list.append(i)
        if i % set_size == 0:
            data = [data_list, set_size, entry]
            q.put(data)
            #time.sleep(.001) #Uncomment to fix problem
            entry = entry + 1
            data_list.clear()

def process_data():
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        for i in data[0]:
            print('Entry: ' + str(data[2]) + ' Data: ' + str(i))


q = multiprocessing.Queue()
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_data, daemon=True)
process.start()

process_queueing()
```

*Note: This code actually shows the data in the queue as being incomplete and incorrect (`Entry: 1 Data: 4 Entry: 1 Data: 5 Entry: 1 Data: 6` (full output) instead of `Entry: 1 Data: 1 Entry: 1 Data: 2 Entry: 1 Data: 3` and so on...) in this example and when run on my Macbook Pro (Python 3.7.3, OSX 10.14.5) doesn't output anything. Again, adding the additional code as a delay fixes all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing
import time

set_size = 3

def process_queueing():
    entry = 1
    data_list = []
    for i in range(1,100):
        data_list.append(i)
        if i % set_size == 0:
            data = [list(data_list), set_size, entry]
            q.put(data)
            # time.sleep(.001) #Uncomment to fix problem
            # print(data)
            entry = entry + 1
            data_list.clear()

def process_data():
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        for i in data[0]:
            print('Entry: ' + str(data[2]) + ' Data: ' + str(i))


q = multiprocessing.Queue()
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_data, daemon=True)
process.start()

process_queueing()
```

OUTPUT

```
Entry: 1 Data: 1
Entry: 1 Data: 2
Entry: 1 Data: 3
Entry: 2 Data: 4
Entry: 2 Data: 5
Entry: 2 Data: 6
Entry: 3 Data: 7
Entry: 3 Data: 8
Entry: 3 Data: 9
Entry: 4 Data: 10
```

I think I got it working, by changing the `data_list` to `list(data_list)`, I think what happens is that you are overwriting the data_list not making a new list every time. I really think you should use something like [`Locks`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock)  for this, to avoid any race conditions like the ones you are facing.

Comment: This is not working for me (and not completely for you if this was your complete result, `Entry` should end at 33 and `Data` should end at 99). I've also tried `data_list.copy()`, but that also does not work. I might be able to use locks, or just time.sleep() to slow down the code, but that doesn't seem like the right way to resolve this issue for code that will be evolving in the future. I'm not sure why this is a problem in the first place.

Comment: @Python3Noob well, thats because you didnt call `process.join()` at the end if that is called. I get the full output, I assumed you already knew this.

Comment: @Python3Noob  `process.join()` which waits for the process  to exit() then only the program will exit() but now you would have to wait for the infinite for loop to exit or put with some other condition to exit from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `data_list.clear()` to `data_list = []` seems to have solved the problem. I also opted to throw the *output* into a queue because `process_data()` is running in a separate process and won't print to my main process stdout when running in the IDLE shell (windows) (there are other solutions for that).

```
import multiprocessing
import time

set_size = 3

def process_queueing(q):
    entry = 1
    data_list = []
    for i in range(1,100):
        data_list.append(i)
        if i % set_size == 0:
            data = [data_list, set_size, entry]
            q.put(data)
            #time.sleep(.001) #Uncomment to fix problem
            entry = entry + 1
##            data_list.clear()
            data_list = []

    return('Done')


def process_data(q,r):
    while True:
        data = q.get()
        for i in data[0]:
            r.put('Entry: ' + str(data[2]) + ' Data: ' + str(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    r = multiprocessing.Queue()

    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_data,
                                      args=(q,r),
                                      daemon=True)
    process.start()

    print(process_queueing(q))
    print('foo')
    print(r.empty())
    #wait for process_data to put stuff on the queue
    while r.empty():
        pass
    while not r.empty():
        data = r.get()
        #hopefully print takes enough time for more things to get put on the queue
        print(data)
```

---

I don't believe the additional queue affects the outcome - although it does introduce a wait for the data to get pickled before putting it on the queue. **Running `py -m tmp` from the powershell command prompt** works fine without the additional queue

**tmp.py**

```
import multiprocessing
from queue import Empty
import time

set_size = 3

def process_queueing(q):
    entry = 1
    data_list = []
    for i in range(1,100):
        data_list.append(i)
        if i % set_size == 0:
            data = [data_list, set_size, entry]
            q.put(data)
            #time.sleep(.001) #Uncomment to fix problem
            entry = entry + 1
##            data_list.clear()
            data_list = []
    q.put('Done')
    return('Done')

def process_data(q,r):
    while True:
        try:
            data = q.get(timeout=1)
            if data == 'Done':
                print('donedone')
                break
            for i in data[0]:
    ##            r.put('Entry: ' + str(data[2]) + ' Data: ' + str(i))
                print('foo Entry: ' + str(data[2]) + ' Data: ' + str(i))
        except Empty:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':

    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    r = multiprocessing.Queue()

    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_data,
                                      args=(q,r),
                                      daemon=True)
    process.start()
    print(process_queueing(q))
    while process.is_alive():
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but changing data_list.clear() to data_list = [] did not solve the issue for me. Unfortunately, small changes that shouldn't affect the output, are affecting it. A small change such as `print('got from queue', data)` after `data = q.get()` in the spawned process start returning results (but not all of them). I have limited characters for a reply, but you can view a [discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/clizmt/queue_skipping_first_item_in_queue/) regarding is issue and a few more suggestions that have not resolved this issue.

Comment: All I can say is that using `data_list.clear()` definitely breaks it. See the edit to the second solution - I added a timeout on `q.get` and broke out of the `while` loop on the Exception to ensure `process` terminates; then a added a *do-nothing* loop to keep the main process alive while `process` is *getting and printing*.. It works for me.

Comment: How does `data_list.clear()` vs `data_list = []` have anything to do with it?

Comment: Beats me but change the commenting on those two lines and it breaks. Did you try it?